# Transactional Replication Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, replication, deadlock

I set up transactional replication between two servers on various tables. I noticed that there were a few deadlocks around the time of the snapshot generation(which it appears is expected).

What I didn't expect is a flood of deadlocks about 15 minutes after replication had completed. Example deadlock:

- user stored procedure has Sch-S lock on Table 1
- replication stored procedure(sp_MSsetfilteredstatus) has Sch-M on Table 2

user proc is waiting for Sch-S on Table 2 while replication stored proc I believe is waiting for a Sch-M on Table 1.

I was under the impression that the transaction log was read from after the snapshot was generated so this would have little to no impact on the server, am I mistaken? Is there something I can do to avoid the ongoing deadlocks?